# Extract same column from multiple excel files using xlsread

Tags: excel, matlab, extract, xlsread

I have a directory on C drive containing a number of excel files of the same format. I would like to copy column H from each file into a new file using the following script I found online:

```
dirs=dir('C:\xxx\*.xlsx');
dircell=struct2cell(dirs);
filenames=dircell(1,:);
range = 'H:H';
n = (numel(filenames));
for i = 1:n;
     Newfile(:,i) = xlsread(filenames{i},range);
end
```

This gives an error message of "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." with only one column extracted in the resulting file (Newfile).

I played around with the range and noticed that error occurs when xlsread reaches the end of the list of the first file and stops when the value is empty. My column H's have different number of filled values (i.e. file 1 has 20, file 2 has 100, file 3 has 3, etc.).

So, my question is whether it is possible to modify this script so that when it encounters an empty cell, either an empty cell or a NaN cell is extracted and most importantly that it will move on to the next column.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not having Matlab at home I have to take it from the top of my head.
Since the column you read, H, has different number of valid entries you should not try to force them into the resulting array NewFile directly but rather use a temporary variable

```
dirs=dir('C:\xxx\*.xlsx');
dircell=struct2cell(dirs);
filenames=dircell(1,:);
range = 'H:H';
n = numel(filenames);
Newfile = NaN*ones(1, n);
for nf = 1:n;
     tempVar = xlsread(filenames{nf},range);
     r = size(NewFile,1); % get number of rows in NewFile
     if length(tempVar) > r
         % Make Newfile big enough to fit column nf
         Newfile = [Newfile;NaN*ones(length(tempVar)-r,n)];
     end
     Newfile(:,nf) = tempVar;
end
```